How to encode unicode to bytes, so that the original string can be retrieved? in python 3.11
In python 3.11 we can encode a string like:
string.encode('ascii', 'backslashreplace')
Which works neatly for say: hellö => hell\\xf6
However when I insert hellö w\\xf6rld I get hell\\xf6 w\\xf6rld
(notice the second one has an literal part that looks like a character escape sequence)
Or in other words the following holds:
'hellö wörld'.encode('ascii', 'backslashreplace') == 'hellö w\\xf6rld'.encode('ascii', 'backslashreplace')

Which obviously means that data has been lost by the encoding.
Is there a way to make python actually encode correctly? So also backslashes are escaped themselves? Or a library to do so?

This question is similar to: Issue in encode/decode in python 3 with non-ascii character. If you believe it’s different, please edit the question, make it clear how it’s different and/or how the answers on that question are not helpful for your problem.

@importrandom the problem is indeed different, as that answer is all about adding the error handling. While my problem is that I added the error handling. I cannot even fathom how they are similar? That's not even like comparing apples and oranges, but like: "how is an apple different from a lake"

Use the unicode_escape codec and no error handler instead of the ascii codec with error handler.  You are getting errors with the data being non-ascii and the error handler is causing the loss.  The result will be only ASCII characters but it will handle the backslashes:
>>> 'hellö wörld'.encode('unicode_escape') == 'hell\\xf6 w\\xf6rld'.encode('unicode_escape')
False
>>> 'hellö wörld'.encode('unicode_escape')
b'hell\\xf6 w\\xf6rld'
>>> 'hell\\xf6 w\\xf6rld'.encode('unicode_escape')
b'hell\\\\xf6 w\\\\xf6rld'

If you don't have an ASCII requirement, then just .encode() (default UTF-8 in Python 3 which handles all Unicode).  Then .decode() to restore.
